# Appium unable to get "content-desc" attribute data

Tags: java, android, appium

In the below case, Appium is correctly able to locate elements by class, but when we want to manipulate the data based on each element's *content-desc* we see an error. Why can't we get attribute for content-desc?
Any advice appreciated.

```
    List<WebElement> arrayOfProperties2 = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.view.View");
    List<WebElement> propertyMarkerEle = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Found arrayOfProperties2 total: "+ arrayOfProperties2.size());

    for (WebElement property : arrayOfProperties2){
        String contentDesc = property.getAttribute("content-desc");
        if (contentDesc.contains("property"))
            propertyMarkerEle.add(property);
```

> Error: Found arrayOfProperties2 total: 32 
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
>   located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: This can help I guess https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5142. I believe the code changes are pushed in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use "name"

`property.getAttribute("name");`

Comment: Hi, driver.findElementByXPath("android.widget.TextView[]").getAttribute("name"); is not getting attribute text from app.. can you tell me where i did wrong in code.. class ,package and content-desc not printing, but remaining node detail print successfully.. i don't know what is the wrong .. Thanks for advance

Comment: it might not have a content description then??

Comment: Post a screenshot from Google automator viewer showing all the attributes

Comment: I have tried like : driver.findElementByXPath("android.widget.TextView[]").getAttribute("content-desc"); but unable to get content-description details even has the content-desc on app element.. i could not able to post app screenshot due to policy restriction. remaining node details print successfully.

Comment: Not sure. When you view the xml source, is the content descriptions visible there?

Comment: Works for me, thanks! It's weird because in UIAutomatorViewer the value does appear under "content-desc" instead of "name".

Comment: @TinyTimZamboni, would you be kind enough to help me understand to get to a solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484982/access-toggle-button-in-android-settings-using-appium-whlie-client-is-written-in

Comment: @S200 the correct string to get content-desc is `contentDescription`. See my answer below. Why `name` works too is because it [falls back](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap/src/io/appium/android/bootstrap/AndroidElement.java#L185) to `contentDescription` if `text` is empty

Answer (score 2):

The list of accepted attribute names can be found in [boolean attrbutes](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap/src/io/appium/android/bootstrap/AndroidElement.java#L94) and [string attributes](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap/src/io/appium/android/bootstrap/AndroidElement.java#L182).

The boolean attributes are:

- enabled
- checkable
- checked
- clickable
- focusable
- focused
- longClickable
- scrollable
- selected
- displayed

The string attibutes are:

- contentDescription
- text
- className
- resourceId

I tested this using the python bindings.

Credit goes to [TikhomirovSergey](https://github.com/TikhomirovSergey) in a [github comment](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/355#issuecomment-206954486).

Answer (score -1):

`text` can be used as

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Remove Contact']"))
```

OR `content-desc` can be used as

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Remove Contact"))

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@content-desc='Remove Contact']"))

driver.findElement(By.name("Remove Contact"))
```

Comment: In python, content-desc does not appear to map to find_element_by_name. Alas!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

`driver.findElement(By.AccessibilityID(""));`